Quantum amplitude amplification to preserve desired amplitudes
I have an entangled state $[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]$.  I want to minimize the $\vert 01 \rangle$ and $\vert 10 \rangle$ amplitudes, and keep the amplitudes for $\vert 00 \rangle$ and $\vert 11 \rangle$ the same, i.e.
$$[x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3] \to [x_0, 0, 0, x_3]$$
Is there a form of the quantum amplitude amplification algorithm that can do this?
Edit: Here is an example circuit that I built using Qiskit 1.0.2
import numpy as np
import qiskit as qk
from qiskit.quantum_info.operators import Operator
from qiskit_aer import StatevectorSimulator

qcirc = qk.QuantumRegister(2,'q')
ccirc = qk.ClassicalRegister(2,'c')
circuit = qk.QuantumCircuit(qcirc,ccirc)

circuit.h(qcirc[0])
circuit.h(qcirc[1])

# rotations
circuit.ry(theta=np.pi/16, qubit=qcirc[0])
circuit.ry(theta=(np.pi/3)**2, qubit=qcirc[1])

# entanglement
circuit.cx(qcirc[0], qcirc[1])

f = Operator([[0, 1, 0, 0], 
              [1, 0, 0, 0], 
              [0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 1, 0]])
circuit.unitary(f, [0,1], label='f')

circuit.draw(output='mpl')

which outputs a circuit:

Then
simulator = StatevectorSimulator()
job = qk.transpile(circuit, simulator)  # execute circuit on qasm simulator
result = simulator.run(job,shots=128).result()  # results from the job
out_state = result.get_statevector()
print(out_state)

outputs a state vector
Statevector([0.75138651+0.j, 0.14900117+0.j, 0.18155846+0.j, 0.61664697+0.j],
            dims=(2, 2))

The aim is to convert this to something like
Statevector([0.75138651+0.j, 0, 0, 0.61664697+0.j],
            dims=(2, 2))


I assume you mean you want to preserve the absolute ratio $|x_0|/|x_3|$? Otherwise your final state will not be normalised.

yes that is correct

Do we have multiple copies of the initial state or a circuit that can prepare them?

Your state is
$$x_0|00\rangle + x_1|01\rangle + x_2|10\rangle + x_3|11\rangle$$
which can be written as
$$(x_0|0\rangle + x_2|1\rangle)|0\rangle + (x_1|0\rangle + x_3|1\rangle)|1\rangle)$$
Assuming that $x_0, x_1, x_2,$ and $x_3$ are real numbers, you can use controlled $R_y$ rotations to convert it into
$$y_0|00\rangle + y_3|11\rangle$$
where $y_0 = \sqrt{x_{0}^2 + x_{2}^2}$, and $y_3 = \sqrt{x_{1}^2 + x_{3}^2}$
Then use XX-YY gate to fix the ratio between the amplitude.
Here is the Qiskit code:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import XXMinusYYGate
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
import numpy as np

x0 = 0.8
x1 = 0.4
x2 = 0.2
x3 = 0.4
psi = Statevector([x0, x1, x2, x3])

circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
circ.prepare_state(psi, [0, 1])
display(Statevector.from_label('00').evolve(circ).draw('latex'))

theta = 2 * np.arctan(x1 / x3)
circ.cry(theta, 0, 1)
display(Statevector.from_label('00').evolve(circ).draw('latex'))

theta = -2 * np.arctan(x2 / x0)
circ.cry(theta, 0, 1, ctrl_state='0')
display(Statevector.from_label('00').evolve(circ).draw('latex'))

y0 = np.sqrt(x0 * x0 + x2 * x2)
y3 = np.sqrt(x1 * x1 + x3 * x3)
theta = -2 * np.arctan((x0 * y3 - x3 * y0) / (x0 * y0 + x3 * y3))
circ.append(XXMinusYYGate(theta, np.pi / 2), [0, 1])
display(Statevector.from_label('00').evolve(circ).draw('latex'))


excellent work - can you please explain how you calculate theta?

If we multiply the unitary matrix of XX-YY gate with the state vector $y_0|00\rangle + y_3|11\rangle$ the result should be $x_0|00\rangle + x_3|11\rangle$. Do the multiplication, you will get two equations that can be solved together to get theta
